# How to use HTML template for email in desktop application?

Tags: java, html, html-email

I have build a small java desktop application that also sends emails. Everything works fine but I want to use a html template for the email. Does anyone how can I do this? 
I have done:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHtmlMsg(htmlString);
```

where htmlString is like this:

```
String htmlString= "<html><table><tr><td width='200px'>Name</td><td width='200px'>Start Date</td><td width='200px'>Deadline</td>"
```

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. You would like to develop your own lightweight template engine?

Comment: No, I just want to send emails that would look nice, for example using a HTML page template. I have created it within my application but I don't know how to integrate it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the template within a `Resource Bundle` file. Usually, these kind of files have  a `.properties` extension and each line of their content follows the pattern `key=value`. These files have to be in the `classpath`.

For instance, if you have a resource bundle file, named `resources.properties` and is placed within a package, named `somepackage` and having the following content:

```
template.email=<html><table><tr><td width='200px'>{1}</td><td width='200px'>{2}</td><td width='200px'>{3}</td>
```

Note that with `{1}`, `{2}` and `{3}` I've marked those pieces of the message, which have to be replaced so that a full message is constructed, when needed.

In order to get all the messages from the resource bundle, you need to do the following:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("somepackage.resources");
Enumeration <String> keys = rb.getKeys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = keys.nextElement();
    String value = rb.getString(key);
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

You can find more info [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file-with-a-resource-bundle.html).

Comment: Thanks but can I use CSS in this case?

Comment: Yes. If you want to refer soms CSS classes, you have to be careful about the path of the `.css` file which holds them